# Airflow HdfsSensor not detecting

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am using Airflow's HdfsSensor to detect hdfs directory. We have kerberised cluster. My code keep poking the directory not detecting like below

```
[2020-08-25 13:57:19,808] {hdfs_sensor.py:100} INFO - Poking for file /tmp/ayush/hive/sensor/event_date=2020-08-25
[2020-08-25 13:58:19,871] {hdfs_sensor.py:100} INFO - Poking for file /tmp/ayush/hive/sensor/event_date=2020-08-25
```

and here is my code

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator, BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.operators.hive_operator import HiveOperator
from airflow.operators.email_operator import EmailOperator
from airflow.sensors.hdfs_sensor import HdfsSensor
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

DAG_ID = 'Sensor_Test'

args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(year=2020, month=8, day=20)
}

dag = DAG(dag_id=DAG_ID,
          default_args=args,
          schedule_interval='30 6 * * *',
          catchup=False)



source_data_sensor = HdfsSensor(
    task_id='source_data_sensor',
    filepath='/tmp/ayush/hive/sensor/event_date={{ ds }}',
    dag=dag
)


dag  >> source_data_sensor
```

Is this the issue with the kerberos or something else

in hdfs_conn_id i am using default hdfs_default in connection

I can also see the directory by using hostname as I provided in connection

Answer (score 0):

provide the HDFS connection ID in the HDFSsensor task

```
hdfs_sense_open = HdfsSensorImp(
        task_id='hdfs_sense_open',
        filepath='/user/xxxx/hosts',
        hdfs_conn_id='hdfs_folder', ##add this 
        dag=dag)
```